# Combine array based on name in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to combine the objects of same array based of name in angular

```
[{
    "name":"Navin",
    "id":"1"
    },
    {
    "name":"Navin",
    "mark1":"98"
    },
    {
    "name":"Navin",
    "mark2":"50"
    }
    ]
```

the output is like

```
[{
"name":"Navin",
"id":"1",
"mark1":"98",
"mark2":"50"
}]
```

Comment: Tried anything as yet?

Comment: can you explain with more data

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the below code.

```
const myObj = [{
  "name":"Navin",
  "id":"1"
  },
  {
  "name":"Navin",
  "mark1":"98"
  },
  {
  "name":"Navin",
  "mark2":"50"
  }
  ];
console.log([myObj.reduce(function(result, current) {
  return Object.assign(result, current);
}, {})]);

console.log([myObj.reduce(((r, c) => Object.assign(r, c)), {})]);

console.log([Object.assign({}, ...myObj)]);
```

Comment: if i give something like this.const myObj = [{
  "name":"Navin",
  "id":"1"
  },
  {
  "name":"Navin",
  "mark1":"98"
  },
  {
  "name":"Navin",
  "mark2":"50"
  },
  
   {
  "name":"sugan",
  "id":"2"
  },
  {
     "name":"sugan",
    "mark1":"20"
  },
  {
    "name":"sugan",
    "mark2":"90"
  }
  ];

Comment: use this one. 
[Object.assign({}, ...myObj)]

Comment: it logging only one data....not all the data were log in the console

Comment: Object can't have same key twice, Can you post the answer what you want?

Comment: Here......[ { "name": "Navin", "id": "1", "mark1": "98", "mark2": "50" },{ "name": "sugan", "id": "2", "mark1": "20", "mark2": "90" } ]

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function to format your data:

```js
let inputData = [
  {
    "name":"Navin",
    "id":"1"
  },
  {
    "name":"Navin",
    "mark1":"98"
  },
  {
    "name":"Navin",
    "mark2":"50"
  }
];

function a(inputData) {
  const uniqueNames = [];
  const finalData = [];
  inputData.map(data => {
    if (uniqueNames.includes(data.name)) {
      finalData.map(fData => {
        if (fData.name === data.name) {
          Object.keys(data).map(dataKey => {
            if(dataKey !== 'name') {
              fData[dataKey] = data[dataKey];
            }
          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      uniqueNames.push(data.name);
      finalData.push(data);
    }
  });
  
  return finalData;
}

let formattedData = a(inputData);
console.log(formattedData);
```